# Add indefinite number of answers to Survey123

Tags: arcgis-survey123

I am looking to create a Survey123 project for a sampling procedure. The sampling will entail the "surveyor" standing at an apparatus capturing information as is needed.

The issue I am having is the number of records per point of capture will be different each time the "surveyor" visits a location.

The procedure will measure a distance and then a value at that given distance. The distance value will change based on site and the total number of distance intervals will be different.

Does Survey123 allow for this type of dynamic data entry?
I haven't found a an answer through online searches, but this may be due the incorrect use of the terminology.

I haven't been able to find anything that allows for this using the Web Creator,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can utilize the "Repeats" methodology for this.

[HERE](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/survey123/desktop/create-surveys/xlsformrepeats.htm) is the documentation for the process.

This will create a group of questions in your survey that can be added repeatedly to your survey results. By default, there is no restriction on the number of times the questions can be repeated.You can set questions for 1 time use and then begin the repeat questions to repeat itself if answered.

[HERE](https://community.esri.com/thread/189915-repeats) is a related GeoNet thread that will answer your related/follow up questions.

"This will create a group of questions in your survey that can be added repeatedly to your survey results. By default, there is no restriction on the number of times the questions can be repeated."

After your Repeats group you can have an additional question and use a calculation to calculate the sum total, or over all average etc...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8RO-3RPRSU

Comment: That is it exactly.